# PHP: Add quotes to each key in json array

Tags: php, json

I am trying to `json_decode` this string, but it's not working because the json key's dont have quotes around them.

**How can I convert this string:**

```
{
    chips: [
        {
            doritos: "yum",
            fritos: -2147483648
        }
    ]
}
```

**Into a valid json string:**

```
{
    "chips": [
        {
            "doritos": "yum",
            "fritos": -2147483648
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: ^because json_decode isnt parsing it

Comment: @skrilled — In JavaScript that is true, in JSON it isn't.

Comment: Where did you get this bad JSON? Can you fix the source?

Comment: Michael - No I cannot edit the source, skrilled - json_decode just returns it as NULL.

Comment: See [this comment](http://php.net/json_decode#95782) on PHP.net on how to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

Not optimal but should work or be a start:

```
$new_json = preg_replace('/([\w\d]+): /', '"$1": ', $old_json);
```

Answer (score -2):

you can try this :

```
 $string  = preg_replace(array('chips','doritos', 'fritos'), array('"chips"', '"doritos"', '"fritos"'), $string);

 echo $string;
```

Comment: The problem is, I don't know all the real key names.